# How to create 2D lists out of a 1D list in python depending upon a length

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, split

I have a list `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`. I want to create 2D list out of it depending upon a 
 length.
Suppose I have the lengths as 3,2,4
So the resultant list must be like `[[1,2,3],[4,5],[6,7,8,9]]`.
Can anyone suggest some way to achieve so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this simply via `itertools.islice`:

```
>>> from itertools import islice
>>> lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
>>> it = iter(lst)
>>> [list(islice(it,i)) for i in [3,2,4]]
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9]]
```

Comment: itertools.islice is a nice one. It worked for me and is quite simple. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do this like:

```
def subdiv(sliceable,lengths):
    idx = 0
    for length in lengths:
        yield sliceable[idx:idx+length]
        idx += length
```

Then you can call it like:

```
>>> list(subdiv([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[3,2,4]))
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9]]
```

This method will work on all things that support slicing. For instance tuples as well:

```
>>> list(subdiv((1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9),[3,2,4]))
[(1, 2, 3), (4, 5), (6, 7, 8, 9)]
```

Finally the `lengths` can originate from any kind of iterable (list, tuple, generator, etc.).

Comment: As my program requires this only once so I may skip using method.

Comment: @BiswajitMaharana: yeah, but this operation looks quite common, so you could define it into a "utility method" you share among different projects.

Comment: I agree that using a function is sensible, but I don't see any advantages of doing it this way compared to using `itertools.islice`?

Comment: @Chris_Rands: well iirc slicing a list is usually more efficient than `islice` since here you work with an iterable. As a result the `list(..)` constructor does not now the size in advance and thus may "expand" several times. But I agree there is not much advantage.